# XML Parsing Structure for App

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, android-xml

I am working on an android app that makes various requests to some servers and parses the xml response from them. I am a novice developer and would really like to structure my app in a easy to maintain and logical fashion. Essentially, i want to build some objects that i can reference throughout my app that are constructed based on the xml that is returned from any of 3 different requests. The first is at login, and the other two are to fetch some client info and related details. How would i go about structuring my application? Would i have a generic xmlparser class that would then be extended to have each specific parser for each of the three requests? And then have three different singleton objects that would hold the data parsed from each of the three respective requests? Any help in designing this framework would be appreciated.

How would theses objects (once filled) be persisted in the app so that different activities can see and use them?

Comment: I'd start with taking a look at https://jaxb.java.net/ for mapping from XML to Objects.

Comment: How exactly do i keep those objects around for other activities to access though...? I read that extending activity when creating the object still may delete the data as the activity can be destroyed by the system

Comment: @JohnBaum, JAXB is almost 9MB in size which is ridiculous for an Android application. Try considering [Simple XML Framework](http://simple.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Why using an external xml parser, Android SDK contains xml pull parser.